# Aurora Serverless cluster topology changed

Tags: jdbc, hikaricp, aws-aurora-serverless

How to implement a solution that will be resistant to Aurora cluster topology changes?

We are using Hibernate with a Hikari connection pool. I've tried advanced jdbc [adapter](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-advanced-jdbc-wrapper/issues/648), but it does not work, it returns me *The topology query returned an invalid topology - no writer instance detected.*

Any suggestions?

We are creating a critical system, so waiting for the connection lifetime timeout to expire is not the solution.